# Adding multiple columns to 1 data frame

Tags: python

I am trying to add a COST file to a sales file in Python. I have cost by variable and month for 6 years. Using a `sumifs` in Excel. I can add 36 months of data and create 36 columns of cost data by doing `EDATE`('Working File'!$X3,plus month) across 36 columns. What would be the best way to duplicate this logic in Python? I have tried Merge that that does not seem like a suitable option as that only brings in 1 month of cost at a time.

I tried:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(sales,cogs, left_on=['CONTRACT_ITEM_START_MTH', 'VAR1'],right_on=['Start Date', 'VAR'], how='left')
```

But that will only bring in 1 column for that month. What else can I try?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of the data you have in a dataframe and the data that you would like to merge into that dataframe?  It would help to better understand the data than can be achieved from reading your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.